# string to bool inline conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, boolean

What I currently have:

```
bool okPress = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ctx.Request["okPress"]) &&
    Convert.ToBoolean(Ctx.Request["okPress"]);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong here, but wouldn't this throw a `FormatException` if the string isn't "`true`/`True`" or "`false`/`False`"? Is there any way to handle the conversion in one row, without having to worry about exceptions? Or do I need to use `Boolean.TryParse`?

Comment: You've answered your own question: use `Boolean.TryParse` :-)

Comment: @dtb Ok, but then I can't use the "inline solution" above, right?

Comment: `Boolean.TryParse` returns `true`, `false` or `cannot parse`. So you need one line for the call, but more than one line to handle each case appropriately.

Comment: No, then it would be 2-line solution... Why do you care about it so much anyway? Your main priorities should be readability and efficiency.

Comment: But how would you do it inline with Boolean.TryParse? You can´t. And yes that´s the exception you would get.

Comment: @walther It isn't a requirement, I was just curious on whether if it was possible or not.

Comment: Why not make things simple ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Boolean.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx):

```
bool okPress;
bool success = Boolean.TryParse(Ctx.Request["okPress"]), out okPress);
```

For what it's worth, here a "one-liner",  create following extension which might be useful especially in LINQ queries:

```
public static bool TryGetBool(this string item)
{
    bool b;
    Boolean.TryParse(item, out b);
    return b; 
}
```

and write:

```
bool okPress = Ctx.Request["okPress"].TryGetBool();
```

Comment: Any reason to declare bool b as false initially? It will always get set by TryParse won't it so it doesn't need to be initialised at all before passing it in...

Comment: @Chris: Does it hurt? I have initialized it with `false` to show the default value of `TryGetBool`.

Comment: It does a little bit... To me it implies that it is doing something. eg that it is setting the default so if you were to change it to true that is what the new default would be. That having been said you've answered my question of why do it. I may not agree with you but I think its probably just a personal coding preference thing. :)

Comment: I've had to fix code where the developer had initialized the variable with the _intent_ to throw away the initialized value (slightly more complicated than a simple `out` like above), but had neglected a certain logical path where it was never reassigned. Of course, the compiler didn't care because they did assign a default _invalid_ value. I'm all in favour of only assigning values that _matter_. I've also seen a lot of usages like the above where inexperienced programmers assign an initial value thinking it will be the "default if the parse fails" value, which of course is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

IF you didn't want to use `TryParse` You could do something like

```
bool okPress = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ctx.Request["okPress"]) &&
(Ctx.Request["okPress"].ToLower()=="true");
```

This way if the string is not true/false it will just assume false for you with no exceptions thrown.

This does of course assume that you are happy for a value of "fish" to be treated as false rather than as an exception.

Better though is to just not do it as a single line. You don't generally have a maximum number of lines of code so two or three simple lines of code are often better than one complicated line of code...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you compare the string against `true`?

```
bool okPress = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ctx.Request["okPress"]) &&
    String.Compare(Ctx.Request["okPress"], "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
```

Comment: It's based on a javascript `confirm()` that will return either "true" or "false".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx) method of `Boolean` class as you said.

> Tries to convert the specified string representation of a logical
>   value to its Boolean equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed.

```
bool result = Boolean.TryParse(Ctx.Request["okPress"]), out okPress);
```

It returns `true` if value was converted successfully; otherwise, `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your inline conversion.

```
    public static bool TryParseAsBoolean(this string expression)
    {
        bool booleanValue;

        bool.TryParse(expression, out booleanValue);

        return booleanValue;
    }

    bool okPress =  Ctx.Request["okPress"].TryParseAsBoolean();
```

Comment: The whole purpose of `TryParse` is to avoid a possible exception. So your code makes not much sense. You will never enter the `Catch` block.

Comment: You're right, that´s what happens when you're doing way to many things at the same time. Thanks for pointing that out though :)

Comment: Since I'm using it on a string, shouldn't it be `this string` ?